# How to dynamically load the content according to the user id in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, using

I have created a link to the users id dynamically
when I click on the link the page is displayed.
I would like to get the data and add it to the template to dynamically load the content according to the user id.

```
function displayPhotographers(jsonfilter){
  
        // jsonfilter est un tableau d'objets
        
        let photographerDetails = "";
        
        jsonfilter.forEach((photographer)=>{ 

          const str = photographer.name;
          const dash = str.replace(" ", "-");
              // Il construit son HTML
              photographerDetails += `
                <div class="user" id=${photographer.id}>
                  <a href="/views/page.html?${photographer.id}">
                  <div class="circle thumb">
                      <div class="crop">
                      <img src="img/${photographer.portrait}" alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <h2 class="name">${photographer.name}</h2>
                  </div>
                  </a>
                  <p class="city">${photographer.city}</p>
                  <p class="tagline">${photographer.tagline}</p>
                  <p class="price">${photographer.price} €/jour</p>
                  <ul class="tags">
                      ${photographer.tags
                        .map((tag) =>
                          `
                      <li>
                          <a href="#" class="${tag}">#${tag}</a>
                      </li>
                  `.trim()
                        )
                        .join("")}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              `;
        })

        return photographerDetails;
       
      
      }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the id from the url of the page you are linking to? If that is the case then the following might help you out:
`var currentUrl = window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

So something like:

```
function get_id(){
  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  var tagLocation = currentUrl.indexof("#");
  if(tagLocation<0){
   console.warn("no id could be found");
   return -1;
  }else{
    return currentUrl.substr(tagLocation);
  }
}
```